# Passing Date into VBA Sub is returning 0

Tags: excel, vba, date

I wrote a `Sub` that takes a parameter `d` as `optional input Date`.

However, when I try to run it with a chosen input d1 the sub transforms this chosen input to 0. Does anywone know why ? and how I can bypass this ? Thank you in advance.

```
Sub run_create_deltas()
    Dim d1 As Date
    d1 = CDate("2022-10-06")
    Debug.Print d1 'This gives me 06/10/2022
    Call create_deltas(d = d1)
    
End Sub

Sub create_deltas(Optional d As Date = "2023-03-10")

Debug.print d 'this gives me 00:00:00 in stead of 06/10/2022


End Sub
```

Comment: You have to call the sub like this `create_deltas d1`

Comment: `Call create_deltas(d1)`

Comment: Thx @Ike ! Why does this happpen ?

Comment: I think you wanted to type `Call create_deltas(d:=d1)` which would be correct and assigns the variable `d1` to the parameter `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the sub with

```
create_deltas d1
call create_deltas(d1)
```

You can also pass the date value as named parameter - you need to use `:=`

```
create_deltas d:=d1
Call create_deltas(d:=d1)
```

All 4 methods are doing the same.

However, you wrote `Call create_deltas(d = d1)` - that is doing something different: VBA will compare the value in `d1` with the value of `d`. Now `d` is not declared, so VBA will create it on the fly (with an empty value). As `d1` is not an empty value, the comparison will be `False` which is represented as number `0`.

You can (and should) avoid that VBA creates variables on the fly by putting `Option Explicit` at the top of your code. In that case, the VBA compiler would have issued the message "Variable not defined" which is a good thing because it shows you that something is wrong with your code.